# Chow Ring of Moduli Space of Abelian Varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties, enumerative-geometry, intersection-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is there a good reference for the structure of the Chow ring of $\mathcal{A}_g$, the moduli space of complex principally polarized abelian varieties? More generally, references for the intersection theory, enumerative geometry, and vector bundles on $\mathcal{A}_g$ would be nice.

Comment: i would think faltings and chai would be a good place to start... i guess you've already looked at that and not found what you want?

Comment: Isn't the point of F-C getting everything (and in particular the theory of compactifications of A_g) to work over Z? I think the questioner is more interested in questions over C; F-C might be a bit daunting with their 14-tuples of degeneration data...

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in things over $\mathbb{C}$, so Faltings-Chai is a bit terrifying to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Van der Geer has written a paper computing what he calls the tautological subring of the chow ring of $\mathcal{A}_g$.  He also computes the tautological ring for a smooth toroidal compactification.

G. van der Geer, Cycles on the Moduli Space of Abelian Varieties, in "Moduli of Curves and Abelian Varieties (The Dutch Intercity Seminar on Moduli)", p. 65-89 (Carel Faber and Eduard Looijenga, editors), Aspects of Mathematics, Vieweg, Wiesbaden 1999.

It is available on the van der Geer's website [here](http://www.science.uva.nl/~geer/publications.html)

Regarding intersection theory,  Erdenberger, Grushevsky, and Hulek have been working on this for the toroidal compactifications, mostly for small values of $g$.  For example, see the following references.

C. Erdenberger,  S. Grushevsky,  K. Hulek,  Intersection theory of toroidal compactifications of $\mathcal{A}_4$.  Bull. London Math. Soc.  38  (2006),  no. 3, 396--400.

C. Erdenberger, S. Grushevsky, K. Hulek,  Some intersection numbers of divisors on toroidal compactifications of $\mathcal{A}_g$.  J. Algebraic Geom.  19  (2010),  no. 1, 99--132.

S. Grushevsky,  Geometry of $\mathcal{A}_g$ and its compactifications.  Algebraic geometry---Seattle 2005. Part 1,  193--234, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 80, Part 1, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI,  2009.